# Selecting distinct attrbutes where count isn't same

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query which selects a distinct list of attributes from all products:

```
products
    .SelectMany(p => p.Attributes)
    .Where(a => a.AttributeGroup.IsProductFilter)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Each attribute is able to be assigned to each product, so I am only wanting a list of attributes where the number of attributes is less than the number of products (as they are used for filtering and there would be no change if the numbers were equal)

I'm not sure how to go about doing this - I thought I need to use `GroupBy` but wasn't sure how to get a list of attributes back:

```
IEnumerable<ProductAttribute> attributes = products.SelectMany(p => p.Attributes).Where(a => a.AttributeGroup.IsProductFilter);
return attributes.GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Where(g => g.Count() < products.Count) // this is now an ienumarable group object so not sure how to get it back to an ienumarable attribute
```

Or this seemed a bit better

```
 attributes.GroupBy(a => a)
      .Where(g => g.Count() < products.Count)
      .Select(g => g.ToList())
      .Distinct()
      .OrderBy(a => a.AttributeGroup.Order) // this doesn't work as a isn't an attribute
```

It's probably really simple but I'm not that great with Linq so any help solving this would be appreciated

Comment: I am not 100% sure of what you want, but if you want to only take a specific amount of attributes you should have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx attributes.Take(products.Count() -1);

Comment: @ChrisWohlert sorry I need a distinct set of attributes, but where before they are distinct, I need to only select attributes where the number of attributes doesn't equal the number of products.  Using `take` will only take attributes from the list, not filter them

Comment: Do Take after all your filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but doesn't `SelectMany` helps here too?

```
return attributes.GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Where(g => g.Count() < products.Count)
    .SelectMany(g => g);  // perhaps Distinct after
```

Comment: Ah perfect, that was simple! I never know when to use select or selectmany - I'll have to read up about it.  Thanks

Comment: @amateur: `Select` returns single items, if you select a sequence/collection you will get it back as it is. `SelectMany` will return a flattened sequence of every item in that sequence. You can't use `SelectMany` if the selected item does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`. `SelectMany` is similar to a nested loop.